# How to restart a sandboxed and custom-compiled Xmonad

Tags: haskell, xmonad

I wanted extend my `xmonad.hs` by moving it into its own sandboxed project environment via `stack`. It turns out that such sandboxing is possible via embedding your xmonad `main` function in a parent `main` that utilizes [xmonad-entryhelper](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-entryhelper-0.1.0.0). Following the instructions in the projects README, converted `xmonad.hs` from this:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  statBar <- spawnPipe myXMobar
  xmonad def
    { terminal            = myTerminal
    , focusFollowsMouse   = myFocusFollowsMouse
    , borderWidth         = myBorderWidth
    , modMask             = myModMask
    , workspaces          = myWorkspaces
    , normalBorderColor   = myNormalBorderColor
    , focusedBorderColor  = myFocusedBorderColor

    -- key bindings
    , keys                = myKeys
    --, mouseBindings       = myMouseBindings

    -- hooks, layouts
    , layoutHook          = myLayoutHook
    , manageHook          = manageHook def <+> myManageHook
    --, handleEventHook     = myEventHook
    , logHook             = myLogHook statBar >> setWMName "LG3D"
    --, startupHook         = myStartupHook
    }
```

To...

```
kaleidoscope :: IO ()
kaleidoscope = do
  statBar <- spawnPipe myXMobar
  xmonad def
    { terminal            = myTerminal
    , focusFollowsMouse   = myFocusFollowsMouse
    , borderWidth         = myBorderWidth
    , modMask             = myModMask
    , workspaces          = myWorkspaces
    , normalBorderColor   = myNormalBorderColor
    , focusedBorderColor  = myFocusedBorderColor

    -- key bindings
    , keys                = myKeys
    --, mouseBindings       = myMouseBindings

    -- hooks, layouts
    , layoutHook          = myLayoutHook
    , manageHook          = manageHook def <+> myManageHook
    --, handleEventHook     = myEventHook
    , logHook             = myLogHook statBar >> setWMName "LG3D"
    --, startupHook         = myStartupHook
    }

main :: IO ()
main = EH.withCustomHelper kaleidoscopeConfig
  where
  kaleidoscopeConfig = EH.defaultConfig
    { EH.run = kaleidoscope
    , EH.compile = \force -> EH.withLock ExitSuccess $ do
        let cmd =
              if force
                then "cd /home/oldmanmike/src/github.com/oldmanmike/kaleidoscope && stack clean && stack build"
                else "cd /home/oldmanmike/src/github.com/oldmanmike/kaleidoscope && stack build"
        EH.compileUsingShell cmd
    , EH.postCompile = EH.defaultPostCompile
    }
```

So, I can now compile my project using `xmonad --recompile` and the binary found in `.xmonad` is soft linked to the binary produced by my sandboxed project.

**But for some reason, `xmonad --restart` doesn't work anymore. What could be tripping it up?**

The command itself doesn't seem to produce any errors from X - it just returns successfully with no sign anything even happened. I trying both the `xmonad --restart` command at the shell and binding `mod-q` in xmonad to either `spawnPipe "xmonad --restart"` or `io sendRestart` - neither seem to work. When I shut down my Xserver and restart it manually, any and all updates show up, but right now hot swapping changes doesn't seem to work. Does it need to see two separate binaries at once - the current one and new one?

**EDIT:** I've been playing around with the problem via reading the source code for `xmonad`, `xmonad-entryhelper`, and `X11`. I'm currently picking apart this:

```
sendRestart :: IO ()
sendRestart = do
    dpy <- openDisplay ""
    rw <- rootWindow dpy $ defaultScreen dpy
    xmonad_restart <- internAtom dpy "XMONAD_RESTART" False
    allocaXEvent $ \e -> do
        setEventType e clientMessage
        setClientMessageEvent e rw xmonad_restart 32 0 currentTime
        sendEvent dpy rw False structureNotifyMask e
    sync dpy False
```

I'm not familiar with the X11 API yet, but what weirds me out is the `internAtom` function and what the purpose of XMONAD_RESTART serves in the client message. There's also this handler:

```
handle e@ClientMessageEvent { ev_message_type = mt } = do
    a <- getAtom "XMONAD_RESTART"
    if (mt == a)
        then restart "xmonad" True
        else broadcastMessage e

handle e = broadcastMessage e -- trace (eventName e) -- ignoring
```

So I'm guessing atoms are just ad-hoc strings used to ID message events?
I don't get any error messages when I run a restart so it would seem as if it makes it all the way to the operation handle:

```
restart :: String -> Bool -> X ()
restart prog resume = do
    broadcastMessage ReleaseResources
    io . flush =<< asks display
    let wsData = show . W.mapLayout show . windowset
        maybeShow (t, Right (PersistentExtension ext)) = Just (t, show ext)
        maybeShow (t, Left str) = Just (t, str)
        maybeShow _ = Nothing
        extState = return . show . catMaybes . map maybeShow . M.toList . extensibleState
    args <- if resume then gets (\s -> "--resume":wsData s:extState s) else return []
    catchIO (executeFile prog True args Nothing)
```

I'm suspecting there's a permission issue here that `xmonad-x86_64-linux` had back when it was compiled and launched by a system installation of xmonad rather than my sandboxed one (which is currently symlinked to the binary produced by stack).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the problem was that I couldn't use the `xmonad` binary produced by stack even though it was in my path and `~/.xmonad/xmonad-x86_64-linux` was symlinked to it. Instead, I got restarting working by binding my mod-q to the following:

```
restart "/home/oldmanmike/.xmonad/xmonad-x86_64-linux" True
```

It will work provided I give it the absolute path.

This makes some sense given an observation earlier that putting the following in my .xinitrc would cause X to crash:

```
exec xmonad
```

Instead, I had to use the following for the initial launch:

```
exec ~/.xmonad/xmonad-x86_64-linux
```

So for now, it would seem as if calling `xmonad` is a lot less reliable of a command and I should just alias the path to `xmonad-x86_64-linux` and call that from now on.